How to create datatable for Future<List<String>>
I need to create a datatable for Future<List<String>>.
A regular datatable accepts a string. I cannot put a future list string.
I was thinking to do FutureBuilder<DataTable>, but it looks like it is easier to use Future<List<String>>
Could you please provide any feedback.
The regular datatable example code is:
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<DataColumn> myDataColumnList = [];
  List<DataRow> myDataRowList = [];
  int i = 1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeColumnsRows();
  }

  void initializeColumnsRows() {
    myDataColumnList.add(DataColumn(label: const Text('My Column Heading')));
    myDataRowList.add(DataRow(cells: <DataCell>[const DataCell(Text('-'))]));
  }

  void addToList() {
    setState(() {
      myDataRowList.add(DataRow(cells: <DataCell>[
        DataCell(Text('x1: ' + i.toString()))
      ]));
      i = i + 1;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextButton(onPressed: addToList, child: const Text('Add to List')),
            DataTable(columns: myDataColumnList,rows: myDataRowList,),],),),);
  }
}


please check this https://github.com/AyushTripathi28/FutureDataTableFormat/blob/main/lib/main.dart, original document https://learnwithayush.medium.com/flutter-data-in-table-format-futurebuilder-json-datatable-1588f32a9f5d
